# adding a foreign key constraint to a primary key column of a table with existing data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to add in a foreign key constraint on a newly created column of an existing table(table A) and the primary key column of a newly created table (table B). This is on sql server 2008. When I add in the relationship the Alter table script fails. I have also made the new column created on table A to allow nulls. 
However when I try to save with NO on Check Existing data - I'm able to save the relationship.
Is this a good way of creating  foreign key constraint on existing data, or should I create a new table (table c) mimicking a many to many relationship instead of adding the new column to table A,which will enable me to create my foreign key constraints without having to specify "No Check" on existing data, although the actual relationship is  one to many.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by making `Checking Existing Data On Creation Or Re-Enabling = No`

> If you do not want to verify new CHECK or FOREIGN KEY constraints against existing data, use WITH NOCHECK

[image: Checking Existing Data On Creation]

Comment: I know I can save the constraint by doing this, but is this the better way of handling this scenario, or by creating a new table as I've mentioned in my question

Comment: Creating other table is not a good idea..even this is also not a good idea as the data would not match the foreign key value..

Comment: do you have any other idea I could use..?